# KMicrohone as an unexpected token in python

Tags: python, speech-recognition, chatbot

I'm trying to create a chatbot, so I instaled speech_recognition, pyttsx3 and PyAudio, and searching through a lot of tutorials I created this:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default microphone as the audio source
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                           # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

However, at the part where it puts `with sr.Microphone as source:` it gives an error, where it puts that Microphone is an unexpected token. I don't know how to solve it. Please help.

Comment: "Unexpected token" doesn't make sense here.  Please copy-and-paste the *entire* error traceback, rather than paraphrasing it.

Comment: it puts ´´´unexpected token 'sr' ´´´

Comment: I don't think you're actually running this code with Python at all.

Comment: Can you please show us full error tracebacke by putting in your post so it wil be better for understanding!